# Is the use of constants in C++ discouraged?

Tags: c++, coding-style

This [style guide](http://geosoft.no/development/cppstyle.html) has been useful to me, but I came across rule #5:

> In general, the use of such constants should be minimized. In many
>   cases implementing the value as a method is a better choice:

```
int getMaxIterations() // NOT: MAX_ITERATIONS = 25
{
    return 25;
}
```

I understand the reasoning from a style point of view: Not only do you do away with the "shouting" constant declarations, but you're also reducing the number of *language constructs* in use (forgive me if this is incorrect terminology), making the program easier to understand.

However, does this approach have a derogatory effect on the compiler, or are modern compilers (or, in fact, older compilers..) able to look-ahead enough to determine that your getMaxIterations function is returning the same number every time?

Indeed, and on second thoughts, does the compiler even need to look ahead?  The style guide suggests the method approach is *better* than using a constant value, would I be right in guessing this is because the "constant" value does not need to be held in memory after its use in whatever scope it's in has been completed?

In summary, my question is: Is the use of constant values discouraged and, if so, why?

(And for bonus points, what are the technical differences between declaring a constant value as a method and as a constant?)

Comment: Yes, they are that smart. The function is inlined with most compilers.

Comment: "*And for bonus points, what are the technical differences between declaring a constant value as a method and as a constant?*" The former cannot be used as a constant expression unless the method is marked `constexpr`. This implies that the former can _never_ be used as a constant expression prior to C++11. There's nothing wrong with real constants – the only sane argument here is against using macros as constants.

Comment: I would argue that one should avoid that style guide, if for no other reason than because it does not use correct terminology.

Comment: This guide is *bad*. `In general, the use of global variables should be avoided. Consider using singleton objects instead.` - wow, just wow. It also doesn't help that it explains virtually every point by `Common practice in the C++ development community.`, which isn't even true. A better practice is to follow the standard and name everything with `snake_case`, aswell as putting constants where they belong - into constant variables. `static const int max_iterations = 25;`.

Comment: Replace all your problems with global state with *another form* of global state!

Comment: _"68. Functions must always have the return value explicitly listed...If not exlicitly listed, C++ implies int return value for functions."_  o_O

Comment: Thanks @JamesMcNellis and Xeo, I've clearly made a bad choice of guide. Would you be able to link me to a good online guide?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can't think of one.  I've never been much a fan of so-called "style guides" because they conflate good practices for building clean, correct code with trivial, irrelevant rules about code formatting, naming, and other related things.  If you are looking for good guides that explain good C++ programming practices, I would recommend the _Effective C++_ and _Exceptional C++_ series of books by Meyers and Sutter, respectively.

Comment: I personally think that there is no general purpose "style guide" (and this one wasn't even about style only), as naming conventions, for example, a completely domain-specific for your codebase. The most important rule: *be consistent*.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis : With one exception – _Effective C++_ strongly encourages returning const objects from functions, which in C++11 is very bad advice.

Comment: I'll add lead to the shotgun shell and agree with the consensus. That style guide would better serve you smolder in the bottom of your fireplace. At least then it will keep you warm for an hour. Full texts from highly respected engineers will serve you far better, and the ones James pointed out are some excellent ones. Even those have quirks that change with the times. there is no substitute for very well developed professionally written *code*. learn from that as well.

Comment: @ildjarn:  _Exceptional C++_ argues the same (Item 43, [Const Correctness](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/006.htm)).  The books could definitely use an update for C++11, yes, but on the other hand, following all of the recommendations in those books would be better than following none of them :-)  So, they're a good starting point.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis : Oh, agreed, I didn't mean to imply that they aren't great recommendations.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Thanks for the advice, I will look up those books today and keep an eye out for updates.  I've just started learning C++ for fun at home, but I'm thinking my more ingrained ASP.NET industry background has wiped away all my good old C knowledge from Uni days... I hesitate to admit I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express as my C++ compiler at home...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is inlined with most compilers.

With that said, the style guide is making a point. It says instead of doing this:

```
#define FOO_MAX_ITERATIONS 25
struct Foo {
  void do_it() { for(int i = 0; i < FOO_MAX_ITERATIONS; i++) iterate(); }
};
```

Should instead be this:

```
struct Foo {
  int getMaxIterations() { return 25; }
  void do_it() { for(int i = 0; i < getMaxIterations(); i++) iterate(); }
};
```

As you can see it's much more consistent and readable in the long run, and good for design down the road, such as when you inherit from the class. Later on, you may want getMaxIterations() to be modified at run-time, and you won't have to do an ugly hack like #define FOO_MAX_ITERATIONS someMethod().

If you're using any sane C++11 compiler (i.e. not Visual Studio), such functions should additionally be declared as so:

```
struct Foo {
  constexpr int getMaxIterations() { return 25; }
  void do_it() { for(int i = 0; i < getMaxIterations(); i++) iterate(); }
};
```

Note constexpr in the declaration of getMaxIterations() there. That tells the C++11 compiler that it is a "constant expression," and it can be evaluated at compile time. By doing this, it can directly replace getMaxIteratsion() with 25 before compiling, among many, many other things, such as allowing you to use it in other compile time declarations.

Comment: YAGNI definitely applies to "May want to define getMaxIterations() at runtime later".

Answer (score 4):

One reason is what Bertrand Meyer calls "the principle of uniform reference" (IIRC).

He used the example of a bank account and the current balance.  Should this be a data member or function/method?  Meyer argues that this type of decision is likely to change, possibly several times, over the lifetime of a software project.  Therefore, even if the balance is currently represented as a data member, you should wrap it in a getter.  Then, even if the implementation has to change, the *interface* won't have to change ... and therefore clients of this class are insulated from the implementation change.

Put another way, even though this is a constant *now*, you may find yourself at a point where it's something you need to calculate.

And, as others have noted, any modern compiler is (hopefully) smart enough that they'll inline the method implementation and you won't incur a performance penalty from making it a method.

Comment: Method? This isn't Java you know.

Comment: @Drise: But everyone knows what it means anyway.

Answer (score 3):

No. In fact, it's *encouraged*. Compilers prior to `constexpr` (and there are many, even the latest MSVC) cannot use a function call as a constant value.

```
std::array<int, getMaxIterations()> arr; // bad
std::array<int, MaxIterations> arr; // fine
```

That guide is a giant pile of wrong. Consider 44

> The parts of a class must be sorted public, protected and private [2][3]. All sections must be identified explicitly. Not applicable sections should be left out.

This is plain wrong. It's often necessary to interleave them because public APIs depend on private things. This strict ordering forbids several kinds of API, purely because of the declaration order. A simple example is where you return a private type- often used for proxy objects, expression templates and such, or where the implementation of the public method depends on a private template method, which must be fully defined before it can be used.

Comment: Encouraging poor C++ practice because Visual Studio is stupid is a poor reason. This should instead read something like "if you are using a non-standards conforming compiler which doesn't support constexpr."

Comment: There's no reason to prefer `getMaxIterations()` over `MaxIterations` when it's a non-computed value. Extra compatibility is just an added bonus.

Comment: If you're that concerned, then it should be declared as a const static class member, so it can be referred to as Foo::maxIterations

Comment: Can you give an example of why declaring class access modifiers in any order other than `public`, `protected`, `private` would make a difference besides making it more difficult to follow?

Answer (score 0):

There is one huge difference between declaring a constant value and using a method in a way that this style guide suggest.

The method declaration:

```
int getMaxIterations()
{
  return 25;
}
```

implies that obtaining the value of getMaxIterations can modify the state of an object on which the method is called. This means that you can not learn what is max iterations value for a const object. It also means that the method can be unsafe to call in a multithreaded environment. This is obviously incorrect, the method should be declared as:

```
int getMaxIterations() const;
```